# Unable to install React Native Maps

Tags: typescript, react-native, package, maps, expo

I am studying and developing a React native project using Expo, when trying to install React Native Maps( command **expo install react-native-maps**) the error below occurs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP3i1.png

Due to this problem I went in search of other alternatives to install the package, and used the command "**npm install react-native-maps --save-exact**" the installation was successful ,
however when running the command "**npm audit fix**" I was informed that the package "**undefined@react-native/maps**" was not installed .

In order to solve this error a tried install this package using the command "**npm install undefined@react-native/maps**" and the erro below occurs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3AW5.png

Comment: Are you able to add other packages? Especially from `@react-native-community/*`.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to add the packages from `@react-native-community/*` and `@react-navigation/*` without any problems .

Comment: I did some tests now and the problem stopped occurring. Thanks a lot for the help .